# add MouseButtonEventArgs to userControl in wpf

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls

I have a usercontrol. This usercontrol has a button that when you click on it, It has to get the mouse position for mainWindow and show a message. the problem is that for getting the mouse position, The event has to be a "MouseButtonEventArgs" event but you can only add "RoutedEventArgs"
to user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the mouse position relative to your app's MainWindow whenever you want and wihtout using event-handlers at all..

```
Point mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Currect.MainWindow);
```

If you want the position relative to some other UIElement

```
// element can be usercontrol, window dialog, etc..
// it would return negative x,y values if the mouse is out of the element
Point mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(element);
```

Comment: That worked but when the mouse gets out of the user control. It doesn't work any more. Have set it to all of the applicatio no matter where the mouse goes

Comment: What does `Mouse.GetPosition(userControl);` returns when the mouse is out of the usercontrol?

Comment: Yeah I know. Is there a way to get mouse position of the window. no matter where the mouse goes?

Comment: `MouseMove` and `PreviewMouseMove` will not be triggered when the mouse goes out of the control, there, you can get the mouse position using `Mouse.GetPosition(uiElement);`, if you want to get the position frequently, you can put this call in a `DispatcherTimer`